# How do I manually call a UIView's touch event on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

How do I manually touch a UIView means programattically.

I want to touch a view inside a UIScrollView touch manually.

Any idea how to do this?

Or how do I manually call UIScrollView's scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is not intended to be used manually. You're better off adding a degree of indirection by adding a method.

Add a method that contains the functionality you want from the manual call

`(void)manualFunctionality {...}`

Then include a call to that method in your implementation of the `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating` method.

This way, you are in accordance with the SDK's original intention and you can call your new method manually as much as you want.